# How do I have a 100% width DIV with a box-shadow that doesn't extend the horizontal scroll bar?

Tags: css

```
#top_menu {
    background-color: #175274;
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px #000;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

That's what I have now, but because the box shadow has a radius, it extends the width of the DIV automatically which creates a horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a wrapper with `overflow:hidden; width:100%` and remove `overflow` from element that have `box-shadow`.